# "Import of key(s) didn't help, wrong key(s)?"

Tags: linux, fedora, gnupg, package-management, packages

## What I need

I'm trying to install the OwnCloud client on Fedora 23.

## What I did

The ["install" section of the official site](https://owncloud.org/install/#install-clients) points to [this repository](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:desktop&package=owncloud-client), whose page instructed me to perform the following commands:

```
dnf config-manager --add-repo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:desktop/Fedora_23/isv:ownCloud:desktop.repo
dnf install owncloud-client
```

## What I got

However, I get the following error message

```
Total download size: 13 M
Installed size: 46 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
```

(...)

```
Total      2.1 MB/s |  13 MB     00:06
```

(...)

```
warning: /var/cache/dnf/isv_ownCloud_desktop-e9a80f76e6d41e49/packages/owncloud-client-2.2.3-1.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID ba684223: NOKEY
Importing GPG key 0x557BEFF9:
 Userid     : "isv:ownCloud OBS Project <isv:ownCloud@build.opensuse.org>"
 Fingerprint: 1B07 204C D71B 690D 409F 57D2 4ABE 1AC7 557B EFF9
 From       : http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Fedora_23//repodata/repomd.xml.key
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Key imported successfully
Import of key(s) didn't help, wrong key(s)?
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: 


Public key for owncloud-client-2.2.3-1.1.x86_64.rpm is not installedFailing package is: owncloud-client-2.2.3-1.1.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Fedora_23//repodata/repomd.xml.key
```

## What I tried

I tried `dnf clean all && dnf update` with no apparent change.

I tried importing the key with `gpg --recv-keys 557BEFF9` but the issue persists:

```
gpg: requesting key 557BEFF9 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: key 557BEFF9: "isv:ownCloud OBS Project <isv:ownCloud@build.opensuse.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

Importing the `ba684223` key mentioned in the `dnf` warning didn't help:

```
gpg --recv-keys ba684223
gpg: requesting key BA684223 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: key BA684223: public key "isv:ownCloud OBS Project <isv:ownCloud@build.opensuse.org>" imported
gpg: public key EE700699 is 992376336 seconds newer than the signature
gpg: public key EE700699 is 992376336 seconds newer than the signature
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Número total processado: 1
gpg:               importados: 1
```

I've read [this related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132757/how-to-automatically-accept-epel-gpg-key) but I don't understand if it applies here.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think it is an official guide? These are some SUSE repositories.

OwnCloud is packaged in [official Fedora repositories](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/rpms/owncloud-client/) so the only thing you needed was to run `dnf install owncloud-client` (after removing this SUSE repository).

Comment: ok. And why don't you install the packages from Fedora?

Comment: I'd rather **understand** what's the issue causing the “Import of key(s) didn't help, wrong key(s)?” error, for when there's no equivalent package in the official repos.

Comment: It means that the packages are signed, you requested the GPG verification (`gpgcheck=1`), but the appropriate key verifying the signatures is not properly attached or able to download (or the packages were signed by completely different key). To resolve this, you should probably contact the maintainers of the site providing these packages and describe this problem. To workaround it, remove the `gpgcheck=1` from the `repo` file or use `--nogpgcheck` option to the `dnf` (not recommended).